# Ordering forum threads by most viewed count in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables of which are:

```
threads {
 `id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY
 `by` int(11)
 `forum` int(11)
 `title` text 
 `content` text
 `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP }

views {
 `thread_id` int(11)
 `forum_id` int(11)
 `user_id` int(11)
 `time_viewed` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP }
```

My aim is to select the threads with the most views, in order, using these two tables.

I tried researching but i can't even wrap my head around how to do this in SQL.

Comment: You probably want your id-type columns set `AUTO_INCREMENT` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, already is, i just forgot to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

`SELECT t.id, count(v.thread_id) as count from threads t, views v where t.id=v.thread_id group by t.id order by count DESC;`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*,
       COUNT(v.thread_id)
FROM threads t
JOIN views v ON t.id = v.thread_id
GROUP BY v.thread_id
ORDER BY v.thread_id DESC
```

if you want only threads that have a higher view count than x then you can add the following at the end

```
HAVING COUNT(v.thread_id) >= x
```

if you need the TOP 10 threads then you should add this at the end (instead of the previous rule)

```
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: That would actually take far longer to process than just using LIMIT

Comment: Depends on what he wants. If it's top 10 then yes use LIMIT

Comment: This returns `A mySQLi error occured: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(v.thread_id) FROM threads t JOIN views v ON t.id = v.thread_id ORDER BY' at line 2`

Comment: Forgot to add a comma  after `t.*`

Comment: Still returning errors: `A mySQLi error occured: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY v.thread_id' at line 6`

Comment: Try changing the order of GROUP BY and ORDER BY. I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.id, COUNT(TV.thread_id)
FROM threads T LEFT JOIN views TV ON T.id = TV.thread_id
ORDER BY COUNT(TV.thread_id) DESC
GROUP BY T.id
```

You could add a LIMIT 10 to the end of the statment to get the top 10 most popular threads.

Comment: Error: `A mySQLi error occured: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY T.thread_id' at line 4`

Comment: sorry about that, I fixed the column name from `thread_id ` to `id`. lemme know if it works out! good luck!